# PHP-AMQPLIB: RPC -> RPC queue leaves unack messages behind

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp, php-amqp

I have a couple PHP RPC-type consumers (brokers) that are perma-attached to RMQ for event-consumption.

One broker is on a remote system - however, for dev/test purposes, I am running the "remote" broker locally.

There's the app-facing brokers, one of which (broker Au) handles request and during processing, creates a new AMQP connection to the remote broker via a contained class, publishes the request to the remote broker (broker Vu).

Broker Vu consumes the request, publishes the return payload back to broker Au - and calls the basic_ack() method.

Broker Au unpacks the return payload from Broker Vu and returns it's payload to the PHP client which correctly displays the results.

recap:

testProgram --> instantiates testClass1 which prints-out the callback queue name: (*ex: amq.gen-6_EhL_eb3HcLiiOb-TUNRA*) , publishes request to broker Au

broker Au --> instantiates class2 which prints out the callback queue name: (*ex: amq.gen-J0jhxeMAf1XZSbHZJ8NZ3g*), publishes request to broker Vu

broker Vu --> does stuff (successfully), returns payload to broker Au, calls basic_ack()

broker Au --> decodes return payload and generates its own return payload to testProgram and calls basic_ack().

testProgram --> displays results and ends

What I see in the RMQ admin console, in the Queues tab, at this point are:

all my connected brokers (AD = true)
and 
(*amq.gen-J0jhxeMAf1XZSbHZJ8NZ3g*) showing Ready: 0, Unacked: 1, Total: 1

For as many requests as I submit, the generated callback queues increase accordingly.

In the broker Vu, I have a ping event handler -- all it does is say "yup - I'm here" and returns a true.  This event also generates orphaned generated callback queue orphans.

I've got all my shutdown methods registered in the brokers - if I try to explicitly close the channel/connection in the connection-client (following the $channel->wait()), it works the first time and crashes the broker the second time it executes.

If I run a test program that connects to broker Vu directly and submits the same event request, no amqp-generated queues are orphaned.  This is definitely something happening because of the broker-on-broker publish/consume process.

Thanks for persisting through... any help appreciated!

--mike

Answer (score 0):

In the client class, instantiated in Broker Vu, I added an explicit channel close() call after the wait() and prior to returning the payload.

This cleans-up the amqp-generated queues.

adding an explicit connection close causes the broker to crash on the second iteration (despite what all published examples show) so I'm just going to leave that out and let this thing do it's thing...

Comment: Do you have logs showing that the broker crashed because of a second connection close? Or is the broker just throwing an exception and it keeps running?

Comment: log files were showing closures but were relatively unhelpful.  broker was self-term'ing (I have extensive exception trapping wrapped around all calls - crash was a trapped exception calling the registered shutdown function) -  on the second iteration (log showing connection closed) so best I could figure out was that the remote amqp connection was getting it's return queues confused.  (Could not duplicate by publishing events directly to second AMQP service.)  Putting in the second connection close (but not the channel close) solved the issue and I moved-on to other stuffs.

Comment: Cool, I find it weird that RabbitMQ would crash for something like this, but anyway, if you ever come back to this pelase report it on our mailing list https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users